NodeJS fetch is tremendously slow with Google API
I use the fetch-node@2 version, and whenever I try to access the Google API via NodeJS, the response time is tremendously and painfully slow. I'm literally waiting 6-8 seconds to retrieve the data. On the other hand, whenever I use the fetch function inside the browser(Chrome), the response time is just fine, somewhere between 800ms to 1.5s, nothing out of the ordinary.
Here is the simple code:


await (await fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    }
})).json();



How come it takes so much time in the backend? I've also tried axios and the native HTTPS library, and they both yield the same horrible result.
I'm working on a sign-in via a Google account, and I definitely can't allow obtaining that data from the client side and shipping it to the backend, despite the good response time. It must get handled by the backend but I can't have an absurd 8-second wait time on the backend..
And for the record, I use only 2 scopes: userinfo.profile and userinfo.email.
Is there any reasonable explanation for why this happens and, most importantly, how to solve it?

Where is this code being executed? What does the round trip time look like when you use cURL or another HTTP client outside of Node to make the same call?

It's hard to know why a request may be slowed down from just looking at some code, but I agree.. give curl a shot first with -v. If it's slow there too that might at least give you a clue at what stage this is happening.
